# How can I Redirect in Asp.net MVC 4 using IE11

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, internet-explorer-11

Develop Environment

```
VS 2010, ASP.net MVC 4, using Area.
Windows 7 
.net Framework 4.0
```

Client Environment

```
IE11 11.0.9600.16428
Windows 7 
.net Framework 4.0
```

After Auth the user info , I need redirct Main page. the Code is

```
public ActionResult Login(string userName, string userPassword)
{
    UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
    .....
    return RedirectToAction("Main", "Index");
}
```

In IE7-IE10, FF, Chrome, this Code is Perfect.

But In IE11, the response is incorrect, the view is loop in login page, whatever the user name and password is or is not correct.

Using F12, Watch the Http Status Code, the Status Code is 302, but in other(FF, Chrome), the Status Code is 200.

```
URL Protocol    Method  Result  Type    Recieved    Cost    
/Home/Login HTTP    POST    302 text/html   .70 KB  265 ms  
/Index/Main HTTP    POST    302 text/html   312 B   125 ms  
/Home/Index?ReturnUrl=%2fIndex%2fMain   HTTP    POST    200 text/html   3.95 KB 78 ms
```

In the Second Line , Result should be 200, but 302.

why? And How to resolve the Redirect? (DO NOT USE Compatibility View）

Comment: As I understand your question, in IE11 the login page is called over and over again. I suspect that this is due to the authentication not working for IE11. Are cookies enabled in your IE11? Can you see the authentication cookie in Fiddler after logging in? If authentication fails, your application will be redirected to the login page over and over again (if you redirect to a protected resource after login).

Comment: After invoke Login(), session have the data, and the next request, asp.net mvc ActionFilter can get the session.And cookie is working.the authentication is success, only the page is not redirect to right.

Comment: Am having the same issue with MVC3.  Only SOME pages (for pages are served up by the same controller) cause a redirect to the logon page, but we seem to be still authentication (we can navigate away to other pages that require an authorized user).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in that the user appeared to be authenticated (the layout would render a menu bar that was only shown if the user was authenticated) but for some pages, the user was redirected to the login page.  This was happening only in IE11, and all other browsers did not have this issue.

The solution in my case was to add `cookieless="UseCookies"` to our `<forms />` configuration element in the `web.config`:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

IE11 now behaves itself.

Also, see [ASP.NET 4.0 forms authentication issues with IE11](http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/aspnet-40-forms-authentication-issues-with-ie11/).  Possibly this is something that's been resolved in a later version.